# adding elements to a singly linked list

Tags: java, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I am writing a method for a singly linked list of integers that will sort them as they are entered. something isn't going right because my lists are all empty, or they have random entries in them.

```
public void add(int newEntry){
    Node ptr = start;
    Node insert = null;

    Node newNode = new Node(newEntry, null);

    if (start == null)
        start = newNode;

    while (ptr != null && newEntry >= ptr.data){
        ptr = ptr.next;
    }

    if (ptr == start)
        start = newNode;
    else 
        insert = newNode;
}
```

Comment: please provide underlying code to constructor Node(newEntry, null);

Comment: Try to debug your code and see yourself that what happens if ptr==str? and same as in the else case, you will find answer yourself.

Also provide the underlying code so that we could see what are you doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not considering all the required edge cases. For this method to work, try something like this:

```
public void add(int newEntry){

    Node newNode = new Node(newEntry, null);

    if (start == null) {
        start = newNode;
    }

    else if (newEntry <= start.data) {
        newNode.next = start;
        start = newNode;
    }

    else {
        Node ptr = start;
        Node prv = null; // save a reference to previous node
        while (ptr != null && newEntry > ptr.data) {
            prv = ptr;
            ptr = ptr.next;
        }
        prv.next = newNode;
        newNode.next = ptr;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
if (start == null)
    start = newNode;
```

You probably want to `return` after this, since you're done adding the `newNode`.

```
if (ptr == start)
    start = newNode;
```

This will cause the old value of `start` to be lost. Presumably you want to connect `newNode` to `start`.

```
else 
    insert = newNode;
```

This doesn't do anything, since `insert` isn't used anywhere else.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to change as little as possible:

```
public void add(int newEntry){
    Node ptr = start;
    Node insert = null;

    // the former if is not necessary, will be handled by if at the end

    while (ptr != null && newEntry >= ptr.data){
        insert = ptr; // the node which will point to the new entry
        ptr = ptr.next;
    }

    Node newNode = new Node(newEntry, ptr); // don't forget the rest of the list!

    if (insert == null)
        start = newNode; // first node of empty list or ordered first
    else
        insert.next = newNode; // insertion point found to insert node after
}
```